# Strange NoClassDefFoundError exception

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I am getting a bizarre case of NoClassDefFoundError exception. My application is deployed on WebLogic 12c and been running there for several months. In one of the classes I am making a static invocation of the method defined in the class which is part of the JAR and that JAR is in the classpath of my Managed Server. Everything was fine until one of a sudden I started to get "NoClassDefFoundError" for that particular class. My JAR hasn't changed, the calling class hasn't changed and the classpath hasn't changed. I checked CLASSPATH thru JVisualVM  and my JAR file is there.

I am wondering is there any way to find out why it's happening through Java utilities or some other tools.

Comment: If there is one thing that could help figure out the problem, it's the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: If you are absolutely sure that you haven't accidentally touched anything, then I would say that it seems like an internal JVM classloader bug. Another guy here had this issue and it seems very rare and difficult to debug: https://coderanch.com/t/556782/java/Suddenly-java-lang-NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: yep, 100% sure nothing was changed, verified it several times. Thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

If it has been running for a long time, it is possible that your PermGen memory that contains static methods and class definitions has garbage collected that class definition in order to replace it with something else. Once you try to call the static method, that class will once again be initialized but if at the moment of initialization something fails (for example you assign a static field's value from a static method that ends up throwing an exception) then the class won't be initialized and when you try to access it you will get a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Comment: Well, Managed server is being bounced fairly often, at least several times a week while other developers update their's implementations.

Comment: Another way this might occur is if a dependency of that class fails to initialize. Even though you won't be calling the failed class, because of the dependency not existing it would again throw a `NoClassDefFoundError` exception